# Python: calling method returns <[object] at [pointer]> instead of object

Tags: python, import, module, python-2.x

I'm a very novice programmer. I'm trying to use the `combinations` tool in the `itertools` module. So I try:

```
from itertools import *
print combinations('12345', 3)
```

but instead of the expected `('123', '124', '125', [...])` I get `<itertools.combinations object at [pointer]>`. I am very confused because calling methods in other modules returns the expected result, for instance:

```
import random
print random.randrange(10)
>>> 9
```

What am I doing wrong with the itertools module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing. The result is what it should be. What you're apparently not accounting for is that the result is an iterator, not a fully evaluated list/tuple of results. The output you see is the `repr()` of that object (it's **not** returning a string). You can convert the former into the latter by passing it to the `list` constructor:

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.combinations('12345', 3))
```

But when you don't need that and you just iterate over the values, it saves a lot of memory by not storing all results at the same time. It also permits avoiding work by not consuming the whole iterator (for example, finding the *first* combination satisfying some condition and then returning).

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.combinations` returns an iterable (you can see the use of the `yield` keyword in the [equivalent codes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) given in the Python doc). You may use `list(combinations(...))` if you want to print the full sequence.

```
>>> print list(combinations('12345', 3))
[('1', '2', '3'), ('1', '2', '4'), ('1', '2', '5'), ('1', '3', '4'), ('1', '3', '5' ('2', '3', '5'), ('2', '4', '5'), ('3', '4', '5')]
```

Comment: Technically, not a generator, just an iterable (of a hand-written class). But yes, it could as well be implemented as generator.

Comment: [OP] Thank you, I figured this out on my own a few minutes after asking the question. I didn't realize that `combinations` returns an iterator as opposed to the actual list. I also figured out that calling `list()` on an iterator will return an actual list. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

That's an iterator. You can convert it into a `list` or `tuple` using `list(combinations('12345', 3))` or `tuple(combinations('12345', 3))`.

By your question I *think* you may have some confusion about what are sequences, iterables and iterators. I think it's useful to fully understand them to be able to write and/or understand python code, so I'll try to give you an explanation on this matter.

The `list` and `tuple` objects are *sequences*. Sequences are objects that support some specific operations. Namely they are *iterables*(you can do `for elem in sequence`), they support "item access"(`sequence[key]` is valid) they have a "length"(`len(sequence)` is valid) and you can check if an item is in the sequence(`elem in sequence` is valid).
[There is a [complete list](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/sequence.html) of operations that constitutes the "sequence protocol". Alas it's specific for the C-API. Nevertheless the names and explanations of those function should give you an idea of the complete set of operations they support]

In python there are two other kind of objects that in some cases can be used instead of sequences: *iterables* and *iterators*.

An iterable is an object that support iteration. Speaking of python an object is iterable if it has an `__iter__` method which returns an iterator.

An iterator is an object that iterates **once** over an iterable and yields the values one by one. In python an iterator is an object that implements the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods(`next` in python2). `__iter__` *usually* "does nothing", simply returns the object itself. The `next` method returns the next value in the iterable.

Now, `combinations('12345', 3)` is an iterable, which means you can loop over it, but you cannot access it's items using `iterable[key]` syntax and you cannot obtain its length with `len`.

Why would you use iterators? In some situations you can avoid having a whole sequence of values into memory to iterate over it. For example, if you want to loop over the numbers `1` to `100` you do not have to create a `list` of length `100` filled with the numbers and iterate over it. Give a value you can compute the next adding `1`.

So basically iterables are a way of reducing memory usage, and in general are an abstraction of the functionality required to "loop over something". If you want a sequence you can convert them as stated before.

A special kind of iterators are the so-called *generators*. Generators are simply iterators that can be written using function-syntax, in particular they use the `yield` keyword:

```
>>> def numbers(n):
...     while n > 0:
...             yield n
...             n -= 1
... 
>>> numbers(5)
<generator object numbers at 0xb744a93c>
>>> for elem in numbers(5):
...     print elem
... 
5
4
3
2
1
```

As you can see when you call `numbers` the code is *not* execute. Instead python creates a generator object, which is an iterator. When you iterate over the object the code inside the function is executed until the `yield` is encountered. When this happens, the "argument" of `yield` is returned and the execution is frozen. When a new iteration begins it starts over.

Probably you can better see the flow of execution in this example:

```
>>> def flow():
...     yield 'Execution stopped here'
...     yield 'Execution continues'
...     yield 'Execution ended'
... 
>>> generator = flow()
>>> next(generator)   #same as generator.__next__()
'Execution stopped here'
>>> next(generator)
'Execution continues'
>>> next(generator)
'Execution ended'
>>> next(generator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

You may be interested in reading the [PEP255](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) in which they were proposed. Actually they have been extended to provide coroutines functionalities, but I think this is enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combination` is a class; as such, calling `itertools.combinations()` returns an instance of instance that class, which can be iterated over to get the values:

```
for combo in combinations('12345', 3):
    print combo
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know much about object-oriented programming however, so I'm still not clear on the behavior of instances of classes.